# Aggregate previous rows in Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table storing activity information for my application's users.

```
| username | day |
|----------|-----|
|   u1     |   1 |
|   u1     |   2 |
|   u1     |   3 |
|     u2   |   2 |
|       u3 |   1 |
|       u3 |   4 |
```

I'd like to be able to get historical data regarding unique and recent users for each day.

- Unique users for day N are all the distinct users that had any activity between day 0 and day N.
- Recent users for day N are all the distinct users that had any activity on day N-1 or day N. In the actual application this will be between day N-30 and N.

I'm able to get the list of the users that were active on each specific day, but I'm not sure how I can aggregate this data to get unique or recent users.

```
SELECT 
day, 
array_agg(username) as day_users
FROM myTable
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;

| day | day_users |
|-----|-----------|
|   1 |  u1,   u3 |
|   2 |  u1,u2    |
|   3 |  u1       |
|   4 |        u3 |
```

For the sample data above, the expected output would be (spacing not required):

```
| day | unique_users | recent_users 
|-----|--------------|-------------
|   1 |     u1,   u3 |     u1,   u3
|   2 |     u1,u2,u3 |     u1,u2,u3
|   3 |     u1,u2,u3 |     u1,u2
|   4 |     u1,u2,u3 |     u1,   u3
```

Relevant SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b793f/1

Comment: hint: use 'lag'

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres and the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom aggregate function:

```
create or replace function array_union(anyarray, anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql
as $$
    select 
        array(
            select unnest($1)
            union
            select unnest($2)
            order by unnest
        )
$$;

create aggregate array_union_agg (anyarray)
(
    sfunc = array_union,
    stype = anyarray
);
```

Use the aggregate as a window function in the query based on yours one:

```
select 
    day, 
    day_users, 
    array_union_agg(day_users) over (order by day) as unique_users,
    array_union_agg(day_users) over (order by day rows between 1 preceding and current row) as recent_users
from (
    select day, array_agg(username) as day_users
    from my_table
    group by day
    order by day
    ) s

 day | day_users | unique_users | recent_users 
-----+-----------+--------------+--------------
   1 | {u1,u3}   | {u1,u3}      | {u1,u3}
   2 | {u1,u2}   | {u1,u2,u3}   | {u1,u2,u3}
   3 | {u1}      | {u1,u2,u3}   | {u1,u2}
   4 | {u3}      | {u1,u2,u3}   | {u1,u3}
(4 rows)
```